# TabLayout Icon Size Not Scaling Correctly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-tablayout

I'm trying to set icons for my tabs in a TabLayout, but the size of the icons keep scaling incorrectly. At first, I tried the setIcon() method, but the resulting icon sizes on the tab were incredibly small.

[image]

After looking around on StackOverflow, people recommended to use setCustomView() instead to display icons on the TabLayout instead. After doing so, the image size expanded to fill each allocated tab space, but depending on the Android version of the device, sometimes the images would appear slightly stretched.

[image]

As you can see on the left, the images are stretched, whereas the images are correctly scaled on the right. The View I am setting the Tab views to is an ImageView, and I currently have the scaleType set to fitCenter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab_icon"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

I've tried setting the scaleType to fitXY, but then the icon image doesn't expand to occupy all available tab space, and looks like the first image. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

(Note: not sure how much this matters, but using setIcon() to display tab icons gave me no problems when I had my compileSdkVersion set to 23. Only when I set compileSdkVersion to 25 did I start having these problems)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `RelativeLayout` as a container of `ImageView`.
2. Use `ImageView` width and height as `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.
3. Add attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to `ImageView`
4. No need to use `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tab_icon"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

FYI, Make sure you have `images` for all `resolution` in your `drawable-XXXXX` folders.

Hope this will help~

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but unfortunately after trying your solution my problem still persists.